# How can I access the parent element properties using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access the parent element properties using jQuery? For example the below code is in my site:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <h3>Testing</h3>
     <p>
        <a style="display: inline-block;" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
            <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3748" src="/wp-content/uploads/BBB336699.png" alt="BBB" height="45">
        </a>
        <a style="display: inline-block;" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
            <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3749" src="/wp-content/uploads/COA336699.png" alt="COA" height="45">
        </a>
        <a style="display: inline-block;" href="http://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/HUD" target="_blank">
            <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3750" src="/wp-content/uploads/HUD336699.png" alt="HUD" height="45">
        </a>
        <a style="display: inline-block;" href="http://www.gmail.com/" target="_blank">
            <img class="alignleft wp-image-3921" src="/wp-content/uploads/HPF336699.png" alt="HPF" height="45">
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

```js
$("a").click(function(event){ 
    var key = window.event.toElement;
    var re = /speridian/gi; 
    if (key.href.search(re) == -1) { 
        alert("it is not"); 
    } 
});
```

When I click the Above Links i am getting an `img` element event properties but I need the `a` element event properties like `toElement`.

Could you anyone please help me out how to get the anchor elements events here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$('img').on('click',function(){ $(this).parent('a'); })`

Comment: Why not just hook the event handler to the `a` instead of the `img`?

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan, I tried this :

 HTML:

<a style="display: inline-block;" href="www.google.com" target="_blank"> 
   <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3748" src="/wp-content/uploads/BBB336699.png" alt="BBB" height="45"></a>

JS:

   $("a").click(function(event){

var key = window.event.toElement

  var re = /speridian/gi;
         
         if ( key.href.search(re) == -1 ){

alert("it is not");

      
}
               
           
});

I am getting Here IMG Event Properties

Comment: Use `this` in the click handler to reference the clicked element

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan, any Example Please

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're using the `window.event`. Use `this` to reference the clicked element instead:

```
$("a").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the page being redirected
    var re = /speridian/gi; 
    if ($(this).prop('href').search(re) == -1) { 
        alert("it is not"); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, It is working fine For me ! Thanks One more time

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

> Use [`.parent(SELECTOR)`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), *Get the parent(**immediate parent**) of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.*

```js
$('img').on('click', function(e) {
  //e.stopPropagation();
  console.log($(this).parent('a').prop('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <h3>Testing</h3>
  <p>
    <a style="display: inline-block;" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3748" src="/wp-content/uploads/BBB336699.png" alt="BBB" height="45">
    </a>
    <a style="display: inline-block;" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
      <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3749" src="/wp-content/uploads/COA336699.png" alt="COA" height="45">
    </a>
    <a style="display: inline-block;" href="http://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/HUD" target="_blank">
      <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3750" src="/wp-content/uploads/HUD336699.png" alt="HUD" height="45">
    </a>
    <a style="display: inline-block;" href="http://www.gmail.com/" target="_blank">
      <img class="alignleft wp-image-3921" src="/wp-content/uploads/HPF336699.png" alt="HPF" height="45">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: When Click on Above Link How can i get the href Value?